# html.routelink does not go to specified route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have bunch of routes defined as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ID",
                url: "{category}/{subcategory}/{lowercategory}/{lowercategory1}/{id}/{ignore}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", ignore = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "LowerCategory1",
                url: "{category}/{subcategory}/{lowercategory}/{lowercategory1}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "LowerCategory",
                url: "{category}/{subcategory}/{lowercategory}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Subcategory",
                url: "{category}/{subcategory}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Category",
                url: "{category}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Now I used routeLink to access default route but its not working.

```
@Html.RouteLink("Create Ad", "Default", new { controller="Electronics",action="Details" })
```

The request goes to home contoller index function. What I am doing wrong. How to use routeLink so that request should go to default route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too.
It seems that the code calls the RouteLink overload with signature

```
RouteLink(string linkText, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

Which means that routeName is never set with this overload and most likely you get an anchor element with an empty href attribute or a link generated with default controller and action, because routeValues is also not set to what you expect.

We want to actually call this overload instead

```
RouteLink(string linkText, string routeName, object routeValues)
```

Which can be ensured by using named arguments like so:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Create Ad", routeName: "Default", routeValues: new { controller="Electronics",action="Details" })
```